# Start video from there where we left

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I am trying to make a video player App in React-native. I want a feature like start video from there where the user left before closing the Application. Any clue?

I am using React-native-video

Comment: Looks like you could probably use [`seek()`](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video#seek).

Comment: if the application is terminated completely the best solution is store the value in local storage and retrieve again when you open the app

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current time from the `video` component by simply running `videoRef.currentTime`.

You can then store this in your localStorage

Comment: Please try to add specific code as a solution.It may help to specific or the other ones

Answer (score 0):

More specifically if you want to achieve this using store/local storage.Please check this out.

```
import Video from "react-native-video"

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.progress = 0
    this.onProgress = this.onProgress.bind(this)

    //Here you can store this progress time to async storage or store.So that 
     when you navigate back to this screen you can either get the progress 
     from storage or from initial state = 0
  }

onProgress = (data) => {
    this.progress = data.currentTime
  }

<Video
     ref={(ref) => { this.player = ref }}
     source={{ uri: '.....' }}
     onProgress={this.onProgress}
     onLoad={() => {
     if (menuVideoProgress > 0)
       this.player.seek(menuVideoProgress)  //here recent progress times comes 
                                              from storage
     }}
 />
```